# checking if windows service is already installed before installing it from c# code

Tags: c#, windows-services

i am learning about windows services 
i installed windows service using a setup project 
made changes to the code in the windows service 
now in the constructor  method of the project installer i am checking if the sercvice is already installed by

```
 ServiceController[] sc = ServiceController.GetServices();
        foreach (ServiceController service in sc)
            if (service.ServiceName == "VService") { flag = false; break; }
            else flag = true;
        if (flag)
        {
            ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj = new ServiceInstaller();
            InstallContext Context = new InstallContext();
            ServiceInstallerObj.Context = Context;
            ServiceInstallerObj.ServiceName = "VService";
            ServiceInstallerObj.Uninstall(null);
        }
```

but i guess this is not uninstalling the windows service cause when i change the version of the setup project in the properties window and run the setup that is generated on build of the project i get an error that the service can not be started as it is already running can any body tell me a work around for this or some other way this can be done. thanks

Comment: Rather than using an arbitrary `flag`, use LINQ, like `var vServices = ServiceController.GetServices().Where(s => s.ServiceName == "VService").ToList(); if (vServices.Any()) { // stop service and uninstall }`

Comment: thanks @nicodemus13 i got your point now how do i uninstall the service (I am using the service controller to stop the service)

Comment: I assumed that @icemanind's code would handle that, does it not?

Comment: actually his code only returns a string that describes the status of the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use code like this:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(SERVICENAME);

switch (sc.Status)
{
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
        return "Running";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
        return "Stopped";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
        return "Paused";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending:
        return "Stopping";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending:
        return "Starting";
    default:
        return "Status Changing";
}
```

The status flag will tell you is the service is running.

Answer (score 0):

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
```